Getting this error in influxdb : " Failed to update task : Invalid flux script
My task :
import "influxdata/influxdb/monitor"
import "influxdata/influxdb/v1"

option task = {name: "Demo3 Grocery Task", every: 1m, offset: 0s}

data =
    from(bucket: "demo3")
        |> range(start: 0)
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "may")
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "order_original_billing_amount")
        |> group(columns: ["marketplace_id"], mode: "by")
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r.marketplace_id == "GROCERY")
        |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: count, createEmpty: false)

// Extracting _value from data directly
reference = data
        |> first(column: "_value")        
        
        
ref= reference._value

check = {
    _check_id: "Demo3 Check",
    _check_name: "Demo3 Grocery Count Check per day",
    _type: "threshold",
    tags: {},
}

// Define crit and ok functions based on ref
crit = (r) => r._value > ref
ok = (r) => r._value <= ref

// Define messageFn to format the message
messageFn = (r) => "Check: ${r._check_name} is: ${r._level} at ${r._time} with value=${r._value}"

// Monitor check based on crit, ok, and messageFn
data
    |> v1["fieldsAsCols"]()
    |> monitor["check"](data: check, messageFn: messageFn, crit: crit, ok: ok)



My data received from the query :



table
_value
_time
marketplace_id




0
888
2024-05-02T00:00:00.000Z
GROCERY


0
830
2024-05-03T00:00:00.000Z
GROCERY


0
744
2024-05-04T00:00:00.000Z
GROCERY


0
600
2024-05-04T00:00:00.000Z
GROCERY



**
I want to assign the first value i.e 888 as ref. How to do?? please help.
**

Try to use first() and findRecord() functions like so:
first_value_table = data |> first()
first_record = first_value_table |> findRecord(fn: (key) => true, idx: 0)
ref = first_record._value

